# Why does the else condition is being executed no matter what?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
correct_answer = "Tushar"
hidden_answer = "------"
lives = 7
correct_answer = correct_answer.split()
hidden_answer = hidden_answer.split()


while lives > 0 :
  guess = input("Please enter your guess \n")
  if guess in correct_answer:
    for characters in correct_answer:
      if guess == characters:
        position = correct_answer.index(characters)
        hidden_answer[position] = guess
    print(hidden_answer)
  else:
    print(hidden_answer)
    lives = lives - 1
    print(lives)
    if lives == 1:
      break
```

Why does in the above code my else condition is being executed even if correct answer contains my guess?

Comment: Can you show an example output?

Comment: please consider debugging before asking . For example in your case you could have used `print(guess, correct_answer)`? so to see what is checked in `if guess in correct_answer`

Answer (score 1):

`correct_answer.split()` is a list containing the words of your string. So it's `['Tushar']`. Unless your guess is the exact word `'Tushar'`, the condition `guess in correct_answer` will be false.

A list of the *characters* in `correct_answer` would be

```
list(correct_answer)
```

instead of

```
correct_answer.split()
```

(You might also want to convert the strings to all be in the same case, unless you want the player to have to guess capitals and lower case letters separately.)